# AWS Amplify App Not Performing CloudFront Redirects on Hosted Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, cname

I have an app that is built and deployed on S3/Cloudfront via AWS Amplify and hosted on a GoDaddy subdomain.  When I go to directly to the Cloudfront url, I can add additional url paths directly in the browser, and the site redirects properly to the root url path (i.e. cloudfront.net/path redirects to cloudfront.net/). However, doing the same things from the hosted subdomain gives a 403 Error - Access Denied.

Cloudfront Redirect rules are configured as follows (this part appears to be working based on the cloudfront url behavior):

```
                "CustomErrorResponses": [
                    {
                        "ErrorCachingMinTTL": 300,
                        "ErrorCode": 400,
                        "ResponseCode": 200,
                        "ResponsePagePath": "/index.html"
                    },
                    {
                        "ErrorCachingMinTTL": 300,
                        "ErrorCode": 403,
                        "ResponseCode": 200,
                        "ResponsePagePath": "/index.html"
                    },
                    {
                        "ErrorCachingMinTTL": 300,
                        "ErrorCode": 404,
                        "ResponseCode": 200,
                        "ResponsePagePath": "/index.html"
                    }
                ]
```

S3 Bucket Policy:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "APIReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ***cloudfront access identity***"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "***s3 bucket url***/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

GoDaddy hosting rule:

app CNAME ***cloudfront url***

Can anyone help point me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you added your custom subdomain (sub.example.com) as an alternate domain name (CNAME) in your CloudFront distribution settings?